# how to get the error message when query is update or not codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, error-handling

## how to get the error message when query is update or not codeigniter

I am using codeigniter library please help
I don't care about the affect row's

```
$ci = &get_instance();
$ci->db->where('activity_id',$activity_id);
$ci->db->update('activity',$activity_data);

if(error){
    return false / or error message ;
}else{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it into variable first

try this

```
$result = $ci->db->update('activity',$activity_data);
if($result){
   return true;
}else{
   return $this->db->_error_message(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply know, whether your data is entered in database or not.

`Model`

```
$row = $this->db->affected_rows()
if($row ){
   return true;
}else{
   return false; 
}
```

Then in `controller` check condition and then you can set the `flash data` and show in the view.

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('err_message', 'Data not updated successfully.');
```

remember that you need to load the session library before use it.

`View`

```
<?php
  if($this->session->flashdata('err_message')){
?>
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('err_message'); ?>
</div>
```

and you can then return the $row that may be have value or empty. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (!(bool)$ci->db->where('activity_id',$activity_id)->update('activity',$activity_data)) 
{
//your error
}
```